# SucesiondeFibonnaci y suma de la sucesion en un resultado S

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso quiero que la serieFibonacci, en primer lugar muestre la lista de numero y despues sume los numero del termino M a N (por ejemplo los fibonaccis de 10 a 1) y que de resultado se muestre en S.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al momento de ejecutar la serieFibonacci en prolog suma el termino diez con su respectivo numero y quiero en este caso que se sumen todos los numeros de la lista y que S sea el resultado de esa suma.

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y cambia las imágenes por texto. Además, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos